# Preventing Grid from resizing when the item height is increased

Tags: grid-layouts

I created a grid of size 200,200 and placed a button in it of size 200×200.

```
Grid[{{Button["Button", Null, ImageSize -> {200, 200}]}}, 
       Background -> Red, ItemSize -> {15, 15}, 
       Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When I tried increasing the width of the button, the edges on the 2 sides didn't appear as expected, but when I increased the height of the button, the grid itself gets enlarged to the button's height. I don't want this enlargement to happen. How can I avoid it?

Comment: Can you provide your code? There are probably a few things happening here but best to see your code first before writing answers.

Comment: `Grid[{{Button["Button", Null, ImageSize -> {200, 200}]}}, 
 Background -> Red, ItemSize -> {15, 15}, 
 Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Frame -> True]`  . Try increasing the width and height of the button.

Comment: If you have the button large than the grid cell what are you wanting to see happen? If the grid cell doesn't expand the alternative is for the button to be partially obscured/cut off. You can achieve that with `Pane`. It is unclear to me what you objective is.

Comment: actually, i want a grid within a panel. The panel height also increases when grid height increases.which i don't want. Can i use a pane within a panel.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest, one could use `Pane` surrounding the `Button`, but then the alignment doesn't work correctly if the button is too large. So instead I'd use `Framed` because you don't seem to want the ability to resize the content, just crop it when it's too large:

```
Grid[{{Framed[Button["Button", Null, ImageSize -> {200, 300}], 
    ImageSize -> {210, 210}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
    FrameMargins -> 0, FrameStyle -> None]}}, Background -> Red, 
 Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: cropped button]

To make this work, I had to specify the size of the item with an explicit `ImageSize` in `Framed`, instead of the `ItemSize` option in `Grid`. Here the button has been resized to be too large in the vertical direction, and you see that it's still centered but cropped at the top and bottom without changing the cell size.

The alternative of using `Pane` is especially useful if your plan is to have the content automatically resize to fit the fixed box, because `Pane` has the option `ImageSizeAction -> "ResizeToFit"`, while `Framed` doesn't allow that.